# assign post ID to new wp.media object

Tags: wordpress, media, uploader

I have a custom form for publishing posts. When the new post is first created, there is no existing post ID, so attaching photos to the post doesn't work until after the post is saved and an ID is generated for the post.

The first thing I've done is initiate an auto-save so that a post ID is generated to represent the new post. However, I'm can't figure out how to update the wp.media object with this new ID so that uploaded posts are assigned to the ID generated during the auto-save.

Is there a way to reinitialize the wp.media object with the new post ID?

## edit

I found this resource, but it doesn't seem to cover how to assign an post ID, and I can't seem to locate it in the source code referenced by the git either...

https://github.com/thomasgriffin/New-Media-Image-Uploader/blob/master/js/media.js

## update

Looks like I was able to reassign the post ID to the wp.media object by simply doing this:

```
wp.media.model.settings.post.id = new_id;
```

However, I'm experiencing some permission issues now. As an admin, everything works fine, but as any other user, I get an error "An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later."

Uploading works fine with all users once the post is saved, but for some reason it won't allow me to upload with non-admin users after assigning a new id to the wp.media object.

R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally sorted it out.

AJAX is used to initiate the auto-save in the background while the user edits the post. When the auto-save ID is returned, it's re-assigned to the wp.media object like this:

```
wp.media.model.settings.post.id = autos_save_id;
```

The permission issue I was experiencing came from the simple fact that my user role didn't have the 'edit_post' capability. Duh.

Comment: Hah, I have done that same operator error. I was just getting ready to post a suggestion to hook and reassign/update the JS obj. Good to be on the same wavelength.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correct the media has an ID just like post/pages. It is up to the editor/system to associate media to post.

When I upload an image (media) to my local dev I edit it via :

```
site.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=19&action=edit
```

Where 19 is the media ID.

if I go to site.com/?p=19 I am forwarded to site.com/?attachment_id=19 and get to see the media.

Regarding the post/page (custom form) - when implemented correctly, on first save (submit) the post gets an ID. That ID remains the same. (beware of autosave post IDs and similar).

Tell me more about what you know regarding the "wp.media object" or let me know if I missed something?

Comment: wp.media is a javascript object that handles the Media Uploader. For example, when you click the Add Media button while editing a post. My questions is, how do tell the wp.media object what post ID to attach the uploads to? Prior to auto save, that ID is 0, after auto save, I need to pass the ID to the wp.media object.

Comment: Cool thx for clarifying. I don't mess w/the JS as much. So, as you said, right after auto-save you get the post ID. W/image upload I grabbed this from the post form/multi-part : ```name="post_id" 25``` making the key/value pair : post_id:25. Once published ?p=25 will take me to the post. This seems to be confirmed by the source : https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/async-upload.php#L75 - so sending up "post_id" in the $_REQUEST ($_POST) should make it stick.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The issue I'm having is reinitializing the wp.media javascript object without requiring the user to first publish/save the post. I've got the post ID after the auto save, now how do I pass it to wp.media via javascript? Standard WordPress post screen seems to do this just fine, I just can't figure out how...

Comment: I gotcha. Lemme' process this (js) a bit in the console and get the JS var to update.